# Changing Django Flatpage Label to another name in Django admin dashboard

Tags: python, django, django-flatpages

Am pretty new to django and am trying to make use of the flatpage module in one of the site am going to create. I am able to setup everything for an admin user to create a page using the flatpage module, but the problem now is that I want to change the Flatpages name thats displayed on the admin dashboard with something sensible for an end user. For example, a name like 'Manage Static Pages' or something like that. From the documents I could understand that META class is what one need to use to change the label but i am not sure how to use it and where to use it. Please help me. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I am very new to Django, too, but here is my attempt:

In your models.py, you need to override the FlatPage model, to provide your own Meta class for it, so you should do something like the below:

```
from django.contrib.flatpages.models import FlatPage


class MyFlatPage(FlatPage):

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Static Page' # your overridden name here
```

This sets up the name for your model which will appear in the admin. You then have to register it to appear in the admin.

```
from myapp.models import MyFlatPage
from django.contrib.flatpages.models import FlatPage


admin.site.unregister(FlatPage)
admin.site.register(MyFlatPage, admin.ModelAdmin)
```

You should then be set! Again, someone may be able to chime in with a better answer. I'm still learning!

Comment: However this will put "Static Page" into the namespace of the App who's models.py you define this in.

Comment: Thanks alol, your suggestion helped me to change the name but on clicking on to flatpages (now with a new name) link, throws an error saying table not found. As I said in my question, am not sure where I will add the code specific to Flatpages (or any other in-build django application). So what I did was to create an APP called common and then created a model.py and admin.py where i added you code. I am sure this is not the way to go but at the same time am not sure where I should add the above said models.py and admin.py files. Any inputs on those things will help me in a great deal. Thanks

Comment: @swarwoop - good point. Not sure if your common app idea is the best one but it seems reasonable to me. I've been struggling with this idea as well. The Django docs are slim on this so far, so I'm looking for whatever method I can find. Thanks.